# Zend 2 check if select query returned NULL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I am using select query using Zend 2 like below.

I need to check if the above result returned NULL (ie) if the Email column is NULL).

```
$checkEmailId = "Select EmailId from UsersNew where HashedUid='".$newUserId."'";
$Emailquery = $this->getUsersNewTable()->checkEmailnull($checkEmailId);

if(Email is Null)
{
   //EMail null
}
else{
   //EMail not null
}
```

**Model file:**

```
public function checkEmailnull($sql){
        $data = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->driver->getConnection()->execute($sql);
        return $data;
}
```

Comment: That does not look like valid PHP code - what is your exact question?

Answer (score 1):

Here "`$Emailquery`" is ResultInterface

```
 $checkEmailId = "Select EmailId from UsersNew where HashedUid='".$newUserId."'";
 $Emailquery = $this->getUsersNewTable()->checkEmailnull($checkEmailId);

//now to get the current record 
$record = $Emailquery->current();

if(is_null($record["EmailId"]))
{
   //EMail null
}
else{
   //EMail not null
}
```